# Meaning of 'The Pits of Fashion'

Tags: slang

In the musical Hamilton, Jefferson states of Hamilton:

> ```
> I get no satisfaction witnessing his fits of passion,
> The way he primps and preens and dresses like the pits of fashion
> ```

Which I would think means that he dresses poorly.  But later, Jefferson addresses Hamilton's sartorial choices yet again:

> He knows nothing of loyalty. 
>   Smells like new money, dresses like fake royalty

Which I would think means that he dresses very extravagantly. This doesn't seem to square with the first statement, so what does dressing like 'the pits of fashion' really mean?

Comment: It's the pits in AmE means bad. The suggestion is fashion in poor taste.

Comment: Wordplay on "fits of passion": http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/strange-fits-of-passion-have-i-known/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Barbara Kipfer & Robert Chapman, *Dictionary of American Slang*, fourth edition (2007), "the pits" has two meanings in U.S. slang:

> **pits,** the ***n phr*** **1** The most loathsome place or situation imaginable : *This school is the pits* **2** The armpits: *Your pits have BO* (1953+)

The first definition is undoubtedly the one intended in *Hamilton*. As Lambie observes in a comment above, Jefferson's assertion that Hamilton "dresses like the pits of fashion" is probably meant to indicate that Hamilton has very poor taste in fashion.

There are two bits of word play going on that undoubtedly influenced the librettist's choice of "dresses like the pits of fashion." First, the expression "the height of fashion" is idiomatic in U.S. English for "very fashionable"; so audiences may recognize "the pits of fashion" as being at the opposite extreme from that. And second, "pits of fashion" is a perfect [spoonerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism) for "fits of passion" in the preceding line. Given the chance to pull off both of those word plays at once, the librettist was evidently more than willing to use a slang phrase that (viewed on its own merits) is thoroughly anachronistic and not in any other way especially apt.